# jquery .when not calling the .done function

Tags: jquery, promise, .when

I am trying to call a function that presents a modal window to the user.  I want to wait for the answer then call another function to perform a save.  My initial function is being called, but the function in the done is not.

I have attempted to use a settimeout and .then with no luck so far.

```
    function _bindProviderSectionSave() {
        //Provider Tab Save
        copyProviderService = 0;
        if (serviceProvider != $("#prov-service-prov").val() || serviceProviderSite != $("#prov-service-prov-site").val()) {
            $.when(copyProvider()).done(function () {
                saveProvider();
            });
        } else saveProvider();
    }

    function copyProvider() {
        dfr = $.Deferred();

        copyProviderService = 0;
        app.showDecisionModal('Copy Service Provider to Service Lines', mg.ServiceProviderCopyWarning, 'Yes', 'No', function () {
            copyProviderService = 1;
        }, function () {
            copyProviderService = 0;
        }, d.close);
        //return _copy;
        return dfr.promise();
    }

function saveProvider() {
        //Provider Tab Save
        var data = {};
        data.AuthPlanHeaderId = g.AuthHeaderId;
        data.RequestingProvider = $("#prov-requesting-provider").val();
        data.RequestingProviderSite = $("#prov-requesting-prov-site").val();
        data.RequestContactName = $("#prov-requesting-name").val();
        data.RequestContactPhoneEmail = $("#prov-requesting-contact").val();
        data.ServiceProvider = $("#prov-service-prov").val();
        data.ServiceProviderSite = $("#prov-service-prov-site").val();
        data.ServiceContactPhoneEmail = $("#prov-service-contact").val();
        data.Facility = $("#prov-facilityId").val();
        data.FacilitySite = $("#prov-facility-site").val();
        data.FacilityContactPhoneEmail = $("#prov-facility-contact").val();
        data.copyServices = copyProviderService;

        let ajaxSettings = {
            values: { data: data, userId: g.userId },
            url: g.appPath + '/ServiceRequest/SaveSRReviewProviders'
        };
        app.ajax(ajaxSettings).done(function () {
            _toggleTabButtons(providerTab, false);
            _toggleControls(providerTab, false);
        }); 
    }
```

The copyProvider function is being called since the modal window is being presented.  However, when I click on either of the modal buttons, it just closes the window and does not proceed to the saveProvider function.

Comment: Forgive my newb question, but how do i resolve the promise?

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `dfr.promise()` to return it to `$.when()`, but you never resolve that promise for `done()` to fire.

To fix this, call `drf.resolve()` and pass the value required, something like the below. Note that it has the added benefit of removing the need for the `copyProviderService` global variable, as the values are passed directly to the required functions.

Finally, as noted by @Bergi, you don't need to call `$.when()` at all, as `copyProvider()` returns a promise itself. Try this:

```js
function copyProvider() {
  var dfr = $.Deferred();
  app.showDecisionModal('Copy Service Provider to Service Lines', mg.ServiceProviderCopyWarning, 'Yes', 'No', function() {
    dfr.resolve(1);
  }, function() {
    dfr.resolve(0);
  }, d.close);
  return dfr.promise();
}

function saveProvider(foo) {
  console.log(foo); // 1 || 0
  // .. the rest of your logic
}

copyProvider().done(function(value) {
  saveProvider(value); // value is the 0 or 1 from the resolved promise.
});
```

Comment: Btw, you should drop the `$.when(…)` wrapper and just call `copyProvider().then(…)` when it already returns a promise